# pandas grouped list aggregation using transform fails with key error

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

How can I apply a `list` function to a grouped `pandas dataframe` which is not aggregated using `apply` but rather `transform`?

For me the following fails with: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['v1', 'v2'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,1,1,2,3,2], 'v1': [1,4,6,7,4,9], 'v2':[0.3, 0.6, 0.4, .1, .2, .8]})
display(df)

def list_function(x):
    #display(x)
    all_values = x[['v1','v2']].drop_duplicates()
    #display(all_values)
    #result = all_values.to_json()
    result = all_values.values
    return result


display(df.groupby(['key']).apply(list_function))
df['list_result'] = df.groupby(['key']).transform(list_function)
df
```

> NOTICE: I know that a join would be possible with the aggregated data, but in this particular case I would prefer not having to do the JOIN afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, in pandas [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and also [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) working with each column separately, so cannot select by multiple columns names like you need.

It is possible only by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

So instead `transform` is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) if match one column, for multiple column use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df['list_result'] = df['key'].map(df.groupby(['key']).apply(list_function))
print (df)

   key  v1   v2                           list_result
0    1   1  0.3  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
1    1   4  0.6  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
2    1   6  0.4  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
3    2   7  0.1              [[7.0, 0.1], [9.0, 0.8]]
4    3   4  0.2                          [[4.0, 0.2]]
5    2   9  0.8              [[7.0, 0.1], [9.0, 0.8]]
```

---

```
#added one column for match by 2 columns sample
df['new'] = 1

s = df.groupby(['key', 'new']).apply(list_function)
df = df.join(s.rename('list_result'), on=['key','new'])
print (df)
   key  v1   v2  new                           list_result
0    1   1  0.3    1  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
1    1   4  0.6    1  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
2    1   6  0.4    1  [[1.0, 0.3], [4.0, 0.6], [6.0, 0.4]]
3    2   7  0.1    1              [[7.0, 0.1], [9.0, 0.8]]
4    3   4  0.2    1                          [[4.0, 0.2]]
5    2   9  0.8    1              [[7.0, 0.1], [9.0, 0.8]]
```

Comment: Still much nicer this way! Great.